# How to prevent user from copy-pasting text with invalid characters into input text field immediately on copy-paste action?

Tags: javascript, onpaste

I have read few answers online and here on stack overflow but I am not finding a solution.

I am trying to prevent user from copy-pasting invalid characters (anything other than a-z A-Z characters) into my input field.  I dont want to do this on submit but on copy-paste event.

If I copy paste text that has all invalid characters (like '`1234`'), my if block will get executed (regex test fails) and that works fine.

However, it does not work if my copied text contains mix of valid or invalid characters (like '`12abc`' or '`abc12`').

How do I prevent user from copy-pasting text with invalid characters into my input text?

I am calling my javascript function on input text element like this:

```js
function validatePaste(e) {
  var regex = /[a-z]/gi;
  var copiedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text')
  console.log(copiedText,regex.test(copiedText) )
  if (!regex.test(copiedText)) {
    e.preventDefault(); //this line executes only if copiedText has all invalid characters
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onpaste="validatePaste(event)">
```

Comment: Are your `valid` characters only numbers ?

Comment: So make your reg exp match a full string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only test there is one char there

Here is a better regex - also we do not need to assign it every time

```js
const regex = /^[a-z]+$/gi; // gi makes A-Z irrelevant

function validatePaste(e) {
  const copiedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text')
  console.log(copiedText, regex.test(copiedText))
  if (!regex.test(copiedText)) {
    e.preventDefault(); //this line executes if copiedText has any invalid characters
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onpaste="validatePaste(event)">
```

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you.  Would you mind explaining why my regex was failing?  Is it because I was missing the "+$" in it?  What does "+$" mean?  Thank you

Comment: ^=from start of field, $ till end. + means one or more. https://regex101.com/r/BhgmhN/1

Comment: how is that different from using * instead of +?  Thanks again

Comment: plus: one or more, * is 0 or more  https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#:~:text=The%20asterisk%20or%20star%20tells,preceding%20token%20once%20or%20more.&text=The%20star%20repeats%20the%20second,second%20character%20class%20matches%20nothing.

Answer (score 1):

References:

Character classes ([...]), Anchors (^ and $), Repetition (+, *)

The / are just delimiters, it denotes the start and the end of the regex. One use of this is now you can use modifiers on it.

```js
function validatePaste(e) {
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
  var copiedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text')
  if (!regex.test(copiedText)) {
    e.preventDefault(); //this line executes only if copiedText has all invalid characters
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onpaste="validatePaste(event)">
```